# matching a value to the closest value in other dataframe by row in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame({5000:[1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,3500,4000,5000],10000:[1000,2000,3000,5000,7500,8500,95000,10000],100000:[1000,2000,5000,10000,20000,50000,75000,100000]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value':[2000,45000,4000,20000]})
```

I'm looking for an efficient way to do the following:
for each value in df1 - look for the column which is the closest and greater than the value, and then look for the closest and lower than the value and use it as the results.

expected output:

[image]

Thanks :)

Comment: Questions related to improving the efficiency of working code are more suited to be asked in the  [Code Review Forum](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Code Review is a question and answer site for peer programmer code reviews. Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: You can look into `pd.merge_asof` to merge dataframes on closest values. However, if your approach requires matching rows of one dataframe to different _columns_ of a second dataframe, that can't be very easily vectorized in pandas. Can you express the problem in a different format?

Comment: @ozacha thanks! that's a great suggestion. I managed to do this by unstacking df2 and using pd.merge_asof twice